# Vue.js trying to get DOM element by ID in computed returns null

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am wondering if it is posible to get elements by their id in Vue.js from a computed function. It is a silly question but for some reason it is giving me null as a response when I try to log this condition.

Let's say these are html tags:

```html
<button id="dice1" class="revol"></button>
<button id="dice2" class="revol"></button>
```

then in one of my computed methods I try to access both ids

```js
computed: {
  roll(){
    document.getElementById("dice1").className += "dic1";
    document.getElementById("dice2").className += "dic2";

    ...some code 
  }
}
```

Due to the error I checked in the created hook what was going on and realize that the `document.getElementById` of any id returns null

```js
created() {
  console.log(document.getElementById("dice1"));
  console.log(document.getElementById("dice1"));
},
```

Also instead of referring straight to the DOM element I initialize variables and assigning the elementsById to them, but the results are the same

```js
rollDice() {
  var  diceFirst= document.getElementById("dice1");
  var diceSecond= document.getElementById("dice2")
  
  diceFirst.className += "dic1";
  diceSecond.className += "dic2";

  ....some code
}
```

How can I improve this situation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Vue lifecycle has no DOM in created hook.

Comment: just checked in created to see what was going on , but since the very begginig the function breaks cause of this problem of null value of the elementById

Comment: You shouldn't be manually manipulating the DOM like that, just bind a value to each element's class.

Comment: Any example on detail Decade Moon?....thanks

Comment: Use `this.$refs` and the `ref` attribute in the template to refer to elements in your template. Also, you should not be manipulating the class names in computed property. Is there a reason why you're doing that? For toggling of classes you should be using the `v-bind:class` directive instead.

Comment: Try using v-model to access the element and detect/do changes. It is very handy and saves lot of time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stemming from Decade Moon's comment, Vue doesn't like it when you manually manipulate the DOM (well, actually, Vue doesn't care, but it's bad practice since detaches your data from its representation in the DOM, which is not what you want when making a datadriven app). Instead, whenever you want to set the class of an element, do it with data (or with a computed property).

Your DOM should be representing your data, not the other way around.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    class1: 'revol',
    class2: 'revol'
  },
  methods: {
    rollDice: function() {
      class1 += 'dic1';
      class2 += 'dic2';
      
      // ... some code
    }
  }
});
```

```
<div id="app">
  <button id="dice1" v-bind:class="class1">Dice 1</button>
  <button id="dice2" v-bind:class="class2">Dice 2</button>
</div>
```

This `rollDice` function does exactly the same thing as yours—it adds a new class to the buttons—but with a data-driven approach instead of trying to manipulate the DOM. In this case, the two `button`s represent the data in `class1` and `class2`, instead of having them decoupled.

Answer (score 3):

The elements in the DOM are only available in the `mounted` hook. In `created`, the DOM elements are not rendered yet so you're unable to get them.

You can also use `$ref` to get the element from the DOM.

```html
  <input type="text" ref="textbox" />
```

In the script, you can access this element using

```js
  let tBox = this.$ref.textbox;
```

`tBox` will hold the input DOM element.

In the snippet below you can see how to get the element by id.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mounted() {
    document.getElementById('header').textContent = 'New Text'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1 id="header">Component Text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: throws undefined for some reason

Comment: @EnriqueGF are you trying inside the mounted() hook? If so, please share your code in codesandbox for further debugging

Comment: im trying it in a computed method

Comment: @EnriqueGF Updated my answer with `mounted` hook. If you want to use it in `computed`, please explain the exact scenario.

Comment: Basically accessing two buttons dom in the html tag, and according to my specifications asigning them a already designed className in my style template

Comment: @EnriqueGF you can add class to the DOM inside `methods` by `document.getElementById('dice1').classList.add('dic1'). `computed` will run on every render so duplicate classes will get added.